# In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at exact version (e.g. "[16.0.0]", but isn't being resolved

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[16.0.   0]", but isn't
>   >     being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will
>   >     be unknown.
>
>   Dependency failing:
>     com.google.firebase:firebase-measurement-connector-impl:16.0.1 ->
>     com.google.android.gms:play-servic   es-measurement-base@[16.0.0], but
>     play-services-measurement-base version was 17.2.0.
>
> The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or
>   have transitive dependencies that lead to the art   ifact with the
>   issue.   -- Project 'app' depends onto
>   com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.1   -- Project 'app' depends
>   onto com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics@17.2.0
>
> For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line
>   with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep   endency
>   paths to the artifact. This error message came from the
>   google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
>   github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding
>   "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your build.gradle
>   file.

Here is my app level build.gradle

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.santosenoque.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Project level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"


}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')


}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I downloaded this project from Github, please help me solve this error.